# WSO2 CEP encode login/password in WSO2 Adapter

Tags: encode, wso2, adaptor, wso2-cep

In (CEP) WSO2 Adaptor login and password have to be write like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outputEventAdaptor name="WSO2_Adaptor" statistics="disable"
  trace="disable" type="wso2event" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventadaptormanager">
  <property name="username">admin</property>
  <property name="receiverURL">tcp://localhost:7611</property>
  <property name="password">admin</property>
  <property name="authenticatorURL">ssl://localhost:7711</property>
</outputEventAdaptor>
```

Is it possible to encode login and password and instead of admin/admin write encoded params, for example MD5 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box in CEP 3.1.0.  But this is available in the upcoming 4.0.0 release (which will be released soon) where all the password fields are encrypted by default [1].

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-1018